# Time Machine + WD my book studio 1 tb

Tags: backup, osx-lion, time-machine

Situation:

- iMac 27" metà 2011
- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4
- WD my book studio 1 tb

It's been 3 weeks of problems with my Time Machine.  Every time I want to overcome the problem I have had to delete the last backup in the external HDD.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for "error setxattr" turned up this on Apple's forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2590108

The advice given there was:

- The volume name may have illegal characters in it
- The permissions on the volume should be checked using Disk Utility
- Make sure the system software is updated (Software Update)
- Try a different port to connect the external drive

Not in that list, but having used WD external drives before, see if there is a firmware update for it.